# Can someone viewing my site see the codebehind in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

Which files can be seen by any viewer (-not someone who has the password to my control panel)?

Can he download the dll which was made from the .cs files?

And what about the web.config, can he see that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web.config and the bin directory are usually protected from being viewed UNLESS you open them up yourself. Also, code files like *.cs or *.vb cannot be seen again excluding the possibility of you allowing them to be seen. Any clients that request a .aspx page will see the rendered version by default.

Answer (score 3):

No... users viewing your site do not have any access to your backend code.

They can only access what you actually output to the browser (IE. HTML files, Javascript, CSS, etc)